# FileIO.ReadAllBytes in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm trying to use `FileIO.ReadAllBytes` and `File.ReadAllBytes` in my Win 8 app but there is an error:

> 'Windows.Storage.FileIO' does not contain a definition for
>   'ReadAllBytes'

My code:

```
byte[] bytes = FileIO.ReadAllBytes(@"image.png");
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
string content = "file1=" + encoded + "";
```

Comment: Isn't it File.ReadAllBytes? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There simply is no such method. And that figures, the FileIO class does not support synchronous methods.

The closest match is [ReadBufferAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readbufferasync). Look at the sample and note the `await` in the call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in this namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.aspx have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx

Comment: ReadTextAsync and ReadAllBytes is the same thinks?

Comment: here is explained how to load resources in Windows Store apps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965322.aspx